# Cannot See What is being Typed In Wordpress Login Page

Tags: wordpress

Cannot See What is being Typed In WordPress Login Page

Please find below the Screenshot.

Text Entered Not Seen Here:

[image: Text Entered Not Seen Here]

I can see if i select the text entered:

[image: I can see if i select the text entered]

Comment: Can you share your site url ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the font color is the same as the login box background color in the CSS.

Select the text with the right click in your browser & click on the `Inspect element`.
Your CSS code may differ from the one below, but it's probably the same. Try to place that code in your Custom CSS in your WP theme & simply change the color codes.

```
.login form .input, .login form input[type=checkbox], .login input[type=text] {
background: #fbfbfb;
color: #ffffff;
}
```